# When I like a photo, video or anything on Facebook, why doesn't it appear on anyone's news feed?

Tags: facebook

This started happening five days ago and I did not change any of my Facebook settings. My friends who are following me and subscribed to me are unable to see all the photos I liked on Facebook. We even tried it with my family members who are following me. I liked a photo, video and status and my relatives checked their news feed, and it still did not display on their news feed.

This is the first time that has happened and has been ongoing for five days now. I also checked my activity log and I see all my liked posts there and it was set to 'friends'.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't appear on a friend's news feed, that friend probably unsubscribed from you. If it doesn't appear on your news feed, that's intended, based on the priority Facebook places on the story. If you meant something else, you need to be more descriptive.

Try checking your activity log.